# Python - Como alterar atributos de uma classe através de outra classe independente

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes, instanciar-objeto

Eu tenho uma classe principal que gera e controla objetos da classe auxiliar. Eu preciso que, ao interagir isoladamente com um desses objetos, a classe principal seja alterada **apenas na instancia atual**.

Segue exemplo:

```
class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.widgets = {}
        self.total = 0

    def create_object(self):
        obj_name = "foo"
        obj_value = 5
        self.widgets[obj_name] = Object(obj_name, obj_value)

    def show_widgets(self):
        print(self.widgets)

    def show_total(self):
        print(self.total)


class Object:
    def __init__(self, obj_name, obj_value):
        self.obj_name = obj_name
        self.obj_value = obj_value

    def add_object(self):
        ***MAIN_CLASS_INSTANCE.total*** += self.obj_value

    def remove_object(self):
        ***MAIN_CLASS_INSTANCE.total*** -= self.obj_value


a1 = MainClass()
a1.widgets["foo"].add_object()
a1.show_total()
```

**Output desejado: 5**

Observações:

- Não gostaria de indicar a instancia manualmente. Ex: **a1.total += self.obj_value**, pois tenho problemas quando crio outras instâncias do MainClass.
- Tentei resolver utilizando herança, mas não consegui.
- Tentei extrair o nome da instancia da MainClass utilizando o **self.__str()** e repassar como atributo para a Class Objetc, mas é apenas uma string e não o objeto.

Answer (score 1):

*Descobri que era só enviar o self com argumento na MainClass.*

```
def create_object(self):
    obj_name = "foo"
    obj_value = 5
    self.widgets[obj_name] = Object(self, obj_name, obj_value)
```

*E definir o atributo na class Object*

```
class Object:
def __init__(self, main_class, obj_name, obj_value):
    self.main_class = main_class
    self.obj_name = obj_name
    self.obj_value = obj_value
```

*Se alguém souber outra opção melhor... eu agradeço*